# bottom left & bottom right of HTML element

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How could I get bottom left x-y & bottom right x-y of any HTML element? I wanted to assign it to another `<div></div>`

Comment: You sure you're not trying to use JS for something that can be done with CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your element will need an ID (or some other way to grab it from the DOM).

In raw Javascript, for the bottom left X coordinate:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('yourElement');  // same as $('#yourElement')
var bottomLeftX = obj.offsetTop + obj .offsetHeight;
```

Comment: You're adding height to the X coordinate. You sure you want to do that?

Comment: Yowch.  Thanks!  Came onto SO to relax after coding for too long...this is what happens.  I should just go home.  :)

Comment: can it be possible in jquery?

Comment: Sure, probably really easy, but I don't use JQuery much so can't help you out sorry.  The algorithm is the same (top+height) and the JQuery methods have got to be easy to find.

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery position() function:

```
var element = $("#element");
var width = element.width();
var height = element.height();
var position = element.position();

var bottomLeftX = position.left;
var bottomLeftY = position.top + height;

var bottomRightX = position.left + width;
var bottomRightY = position.top + height;
```